# Position a Raphael "loading" element within a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, raphael

I am writing a plugin to use to make a loading-like gif using Raphael js. The base of the code is modeled after [this](http://raphaeljs.com/spin-spin-spin.html).

A demo of my plugin can be found on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ColdToast/Aaqaf/).

My problem is that I cannot seem to get the `svg` to be in the center of whatever jquery element is selected. My idea in that fiddle was to place the `svg` inside a `div` that is created and try to center that `div` but I can't seem to get that to work either.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I can get it centered by hacking the margin property of the containing div. Something like this works:

```
$loadingContainer = $('<div class="loading"></div>').css({margin: -(this.innerHeight()/2) + 'px auto'}).appendTo(this),
```

Notice the negative margin... But I am trying to avoid doing that and actually use Rahpael to position the loading-like "gif"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the position and dimensions of the element using

- [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset)
- [`.outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth)
- [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight)
- the closest positioned element to the `.loading` element, with [`.offsetParent()`](http://api.jquery.com/offsetParent), so you can adjust the positioning.

and use those to position your `.loading` element (*with `position:absolute`*)

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Aaqaf/2/